# Filter a Django queryset based on specific manytomany relationships

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-queryset

I have models similar to the Django documentation's pizza example:

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField('Topping')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And a few toppings with the expected pizzas:

```
>>> pepperoni = Topping.objects.create(name='pepperoni')
>>> sausage = Topping.objects.create(name='sausage')
>>> pineapple = Topping.objects.create(name='pineapple')
>>> olives = Topping.objects.create(name='olives')
>>> p1 = Pizza.objects.create(name='Pepperoni')
>>> p1.toppings.add(pepperoni)
>>> p2 = Pizza.objects.create(name='Sausage')
>>> p2.toppings.add(sausage)
>>> p3 = Pizza.objects.create(name='Pepperoni and Sausage')
>>> p3.toppings.add(pepperoni)
>>> p3.toppings.add(sausage)
>>> p4 = Pizza.objects.create(name='Pepperoni and Olives')
>>> p4.toppings.add(pepperoni)
>>> p4.toppings.add(olives)
>>> p5 = Pizza.objects.create(name='Pepperoni and Sausage and Olives')
>>> p5.toppings.add(pepperoni)
>>> p5.toppings.add(sausage)
>>> p5.toppings.add(olives)
>>> ...
```

How can I create a query that will return only return pizzas that have a topping of pepperoni (`p1`), or sausage (`p2`), or both pepperoni or sausage (`p3`)? I do not want pizzas that include pepperoni, sausage, and something else (`p5`).

Something like this will include a pizza that has pepperoni and olives (`p4`), which I don't want:

```
>>> Pizza.objects.filter(toppings__in=[pepperoni, sausage])
```

I can create a list of all toppings except the two I want and use that as an exclusion:

```
>>> toppings_i_do_not_want = Topping.objects.exclude(name__in=['Pepperoni', ['Sausage'])
>>> toppings_i_want = Topping.objects.filter(name__in=['Pepperoni', ['Sausage'])
>>> Pizza.objects.filter(toppings__in=toppings_i_want).exclude(toppings_i_do_not_want)
```

That will result in what I want, but it seems like the performance of such a query would suffer greatly if I'm only interested in two toppings but I have to pass ~100,000 other toppings into the exclude filter.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can count the number of toppings that are `pepperoni` or `sausage` and compare that with the total number of related toppings, if the two match, and the number is larger than `0`, then we can return such pizza:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

Pizza.objects.annotate(
    ntopping=Count('toppings')
).filter(
    ntopping__gte=1,
    ntopping=Count('toppings', filter=Q(toppings__in=[pepperoni, sausage]))
)
```

will exactly do what you want. It will return `Pizza` records for which "there exists a related topping that is in the list `[pepperoni, sausage]`". So for pizza's that have a `pepperoni` topping, a `sausage` topping, or both toppings.

Comment: I only want pizzas that have a pepperoni topping, a sausage topping, or a pepperoni and sausage topping. Not pizzas that have pepperoni and sausage and olives. I will edit the question to clarify this.

Comment: @snchrk: this is exactly what this queryset will retrieve, since we count the *total* number of topings, and say it should be the same as the number of toppings that are only pepperoni and sausage.

Comment: I see. I misunderstood what the filter Q query was doing. This does work. Thanks. The end of your answer ("or these toppings and some extra topping") implies to me that this would match `p5` in my (edited) question, which is not the case.

Comment: @snchrk: thanks. I think I started writing a different answer, and halfway changed it :)